# how to store bytes-arrays with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a project where I need to store 2d arrays of bytes. I used for that purpose nympy arrays, but I just realized that if a byte-array ends with \x00 character, numpy truncate the filal character. Is there a way to avoid that?

Es.

```py
>>> a = np.array([b'abc\x00'])
>>> print(a[0])
b'abc'
```

I expected that `a[0]` is `[b'abc\x00']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should do is to specify the type of the array to `dtype=object`:

```
a = np.array([b'abc\x00'],dtype=object)
```

**Output:**

```
b'abc\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always give way more information about what's surrounding your code, but assuming np is just numpy and nothing weird is happening, your array shouldn't be truncated.
'/x00' is not a printable character, in fact in many languages it's the string terminator.

Anyway, try calling

```
print(a.itemsize)
```

and you will notice the byte is still there.

Comment: Itemsize is 4 because dtype is 'S4'.